# Calling a URL for a premade chart: how do I manage to implement the data for the chart?

Tags: javascript, html, url, bar-chart

I am currently taking a Master's in IT, and I hace come across quite the conundrum. According to my latest assignment, my subject for the week is to "Create a web page that displays a bar chart based on data passed to it from the URL: https://home.ubalt.edu/gwalsh/idia619/data.php

The chart should have five bars and put a text label under each one. When you hit refresh, it should update.

Use this week's lessons as the basis for the drawing and text placement. The API getting is the same as before but instead of a local file, you'll call out to the URL. Using the previous code, you'll get one array element back and you'll be able to access the values with `arr[0].label` where `arr` is the Array and `label` is the element returned. (Hint: Load the url by itself to see the labels)."

So, what is confusing me is this: how should I go about doing exactly that? I have already made the chart, as shown by my code (I recommend opening it in Microsoft Edge). I'm not focused on making it look pretty, and neither is my instructor, my only problem is just what I am missing in order to fulfill the purpose of this assignment, to make it actually serve its purpose.

In the past, I have tried the PHP's arrays, I have tried Ajax, and I have tried JSON, all have not worked.

(The specific values for the PHP are listed above the actual code; for the sake of ease, if I can't figure out how to make this work.)

```
    var arr = ["41","28","10","36","32"]

    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas")
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

    var x = 20
    var y = 200
    var width = 50
    var height = 100

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"
    ctx.fillRect(x,y-arr[0]*10,width,arr[0]*10) 

    ctx.font = "15px Arial"
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[0], x+10, y+20)


    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillRect(75,y-arr[1]*10,width,arr[1]*10) 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[1], 75+10, y+20)


    ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF"
    ctx.fillRect(130,y-arr[2]*10,width,arr[2]*10) 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[2], 130+10, y+20)

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFA500"
    ctx.fillRect(185,y-arr[3]*10,width,arr[3]*10) 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[3], 185+10, y+20)

    ctx.fillStyle = "#006400"
    ctx.fillRect(240,y-arr[4]*10,width,arr[4]*10) 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[4], 240+10, y+20)

    cxt.stroke()
```

The desired/expected result, from what I can gather, is to call the data from the given url and have the chart display the data from said call.

Edit: @Cat suggested a XMLHttpRequest, and it actually worked somewhat! I believe that now, my question is how to get the called data to actually display onto the chart that I created. My updated code (which I borrowed heavily from W3Schools) is below:

```
<head>
<script>
    window.onload = function loadXMLDoc() {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for older browsers
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("myCanvas").innerHTML =
          this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://home.ubalt.edu/gwalsh/idia619/data.php", true);
      xmlhttp.send(canvasLoad);

    }

        function canvasLoad() {

        var arr = ["","","","",""]

        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

        var x = 20
        var y = 200
        var width = 50
        var height = 100

        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"
        ctx.fillRect(x,y-arr[0]*10,width,arr[0]*10) 

        ctx.font = "15px Arial"
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillText(arr[0], x+10, y+20)


        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillRect(75,y-arr[1]*10,width,arr[1]*10) 
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillText(arr[1], 75+10, y+20)


        ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF"
        ctx.fillRect(130,y-arr[2]*10,width,arr[2]*10) 
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillText(arr[2], 130+10, y+20)

        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFA500"
        ctx.fillRect(185,y-arr[3]*10,width,arr[3]*10) 
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillText(arr[3], 185+10, y+20)

        ctx.fillStyle = "#006400"
        ctx.fillRect(240,y-arr[4]*10,width,arr[4]*10) 
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillText(arr[4], 240+10, y+20)

        cxt.stroke()

        console.log(canvasLoad);
    }

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="550" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>


    <script>

    </script>
    </body>
```

Edit 2: @Cat once again was a gracious help with their suggestion, so, for hopefully the last time, I will post the updated code for context, hoping that, now, the chart will look like a chart.

```
<script>
window.onload = function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for older browsers
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("myCanvas").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://home.ubalt.edu/gwalsh/idia619/data.php", true);
  xmlhttp.send(canvasLoad);

    const dataString = '[{ "title":"Random Information", "item01":"43", "item02":"36", "item03":"31", "item04":"16", "item05":"36" }]';
Object.entries(JSON.parse(dataString)[0]).forEach( arr => { console.log(arr); });

}

    function canvasLoad() {

    var arr = ["","","","",""]

    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas")
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

    var x = 20
    var y = 200
    var width = 50
    var height = 100

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"
    ctx.fillRect(x,y-arr[0]*10,width,arr[0]*10) 

    ctx.font = "15px Arial"
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[0], x+10, y+20)


    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillRect(75,y-arr[1]*10,width,arr[1]*10) 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[1], 75+10, y+20)


    ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF"
    ctx.fillRect(130,y-arr[2]*10,width,arr[2]*10) 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[2], 130+10, y+20)

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFA500"
    ctx.fillRect(185,y-arr[3]*10,width,arr[3]*10) 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[3], 185+10, y+20)

    ctx.fillStyle = "#006400"
    ctx.fillRect(240,y-arr[4]*10,width,arr[4]*10) 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(arr[4], 240+10, y+20)

    cxt.stroke()

    console.log(canvasLoad);
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="550" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>


<script>

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You might get the content by sending an XMLHttpRequest from your server if the file's origin either is the same or will allow access via CORS -- and if you can determine the type of the response it will return (eg text/plain or application/json). And your browser has access when it navigates to the source url. (From my Chrome console, I was able to save the array from `document.body.textContent` to my `localStorage`) -- but accessing page content directly (ie not in the console) from a cross-site page might cause similar CORS-related issues. Access to the server makes all of this much easier.

Comment: @Cat Thank you for your suggestion! I tried it, and I got just a bit closer to success! Now my dilemma has somewhat changed: the script is apparently communicating with the data, now what I'm trying to figure out is how to get the information to actually display in the chart that I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the data via an XMLHttpRequest, you probably need to change it from a string to a javascript object with `JSON.parse`. If the printed string looks like `dataString` below, you could extract the values with `Object.entries`, like:

```
const dataString = '[{ "title":"Random Information", "item01":"43", "item02":"36",
 "item03":"31", "item04":"16", "item05":"36" }]';
Object.entries(JSON.parse(dataString)[0]).forEach( entry => { console.log(entry); });
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! I can;t thank you enough for your assistance! Which is why I will ask for it one last time: the data is certainly being displayed in the console, so your solution does work, but I am still having a bit of trouble translating it to the visuals that I created specifically for the data. What would you suggest would be the best thing to get this chart looking like a chart?

Comment: This seems like stuff you're going to need to be able to figure out yourself to succeed in your program, but a javascript object is a comma separated list of key/value pairs, with the values accessible via `myObject.myKey`. So, eg, if a variable called `chartData` contains your parsed JSON object, `var item1 = chartData.item01` will put `43` into `item1`, which you could then add to your `arr` array. For details of why and how this works, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Comment: I think I have a decent understanding. I am more than thankful for your assistance, and again, thank you so much for taking your time on getting me onto the right path!